# Tool to generate Fluent NHibernate mappings

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am trying to integrate NHibernate into an existing application with several hundred tables. Due to the fact that there apparently wasn't a strict adherence to conventions, I am unable to use Automap. As a result, I'm going to use Fluent to manually map over all of the associations.

Rather than doing it by hand, I'm hoping that there is a tool in existance that can either run through my solution or the database and stub out mappings.

Does anyone know of any project out there with this in mind?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LLBLGen Pro V3 will do exactly this, it can generate either tradition .hbm.xml or fluent mappings for your entire database.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a tool that does it in Fluent, but there are plenty of options for doing it with the old hbm xml files. CodeSmith and MyGeneration are two that are recommended as a starting point for your classes and hbms.

Comment: Thanks man, it appears MyGeneration will generate out fluent with the appropriate templates.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, maybe still relevant to some. If you are looking for an open source solution, try [NHibernate Mapping Generator](http://nmg.codeplex.com)